# Avoid using cookies to storage session ID in flask

Tags: flask, session, cookies, iframe, jwt

I've a Flask app that uses flask-session to manage the sessions. My app is running in my host and it is possible to access to it by visiting 'https://app.mysiteurl.com'.
Also, my app is embbeded into the product page of my clients ecommerces using an iframe like this:

```
<iframe id="myapp-iframe" src="https://app.mysiteurl.com/index?referrer=https://www.myclienturl.com/products/product1&sku=ABCD1234" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-modals" style="..."></iframe>
```

Users can login into my app either using email and password or through Google OAuth.

The problem here is that sessions doesn't share between sites when users haven't third-party cookies enabled, I mean: If a user logs in (or logs out, or modifies something in his account) in the iframe embedded in a client's page, he doesn't log in in the other clients' pages or in my site.

There is any way to avoid using cookies to share the session ID? for example using a token in the URL params or localStorage? I've checked the flask-session docs but i couldn't find anything, also in google...

This is my flask config:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
```